# Parse BigDecimal from String containing a number in arbitrary format

Tags: java, bigdecimal, number-formatting

We read data from XLS cells formatted as text.

The cell hopefully contains a number, output will be a BigDecimal (because of arbitrary precision).

Problem is, the cell format is also arbitrary, which means it may contain numbers like:

- with currency symbols ($1000)
- leading and trailing whitespaces, or whitespaces in between digits (eg. 1 000  )
- digit grouping symbols (eg. 1,000.0)
- of course, negative numbers
- 'o's and 'O's as zeros (eg. 1,ooo.oo)
- others I can't think of

It's mostly because of this last point that **I'm looking for a standard library** that can do all this, and which is configurable, well tested etc.

I looked at Apache first, found nothing but I might be blind... perhaps it's a trivial answer for someone else...

UPDATE: the domain of the question is financial applications. Actually I'm expecting a library where the domain could be an input parameter - financial, scientific, etc. Maybe even more specific: financial with currency symbols? With stock symbols? With distances and other measurement units? I can't believe I'm the first person to think of something like this...

Comment: ideally u should know the column which contains the biginteger

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any library, but you can try that:

- Put your number on a string. (ex: $1,00o,oOO.00)
- Remove all occurrences of $,white-spaces or any other strang symbols you can think of...
- Replace occurrences of o and O.
- Try to parse the number =]

That should solve 99% of the entrys...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do currently. It doesn't feel too professional.

Comment: @Gabor if your data is crap, your logic also has to be crap :-)

Comment: That's right... If you wanna be professional really, make some patterns to your data =]

Answer (score 2):

Buy bunch photos or even better videos with *legal* adult content. Create a web site with these resources but limit the access with captcha which will be displaying unsolved number formats. Create a set of number decoders out of known number formats and create an algorithm which will add new ones based on user solved captchas.

Comment: :-) I needed some minutes to understand that answer. The better the movies, the higher the decoding rate! +1, I like it :)

Comment: Can't decide what to give: +1 / -1 / flag as offensive

Comment: That is what we call "shooting a sparrow with a cannonball". I'm not looking for an AI-strength solution...

Comment: @Gabor Kulcsar Really? Then the question should limit solution domain. There's no way of solving an unknown problem without employing some kind of AI.

Comment: @Boris: it is totally fine to say "I can't parse this number" if it is indeeed erroneous. For an accountant, "O" equals "0", that is one thing I've learned. So they expext "Iooo" to be parsed. I suspect there are other standard expectations like this but because I'm not an accountant I don't know these - that's why I'm looking for some collected wisdom. I'm definitely not looking for AI.

Comment: @Gabor What about roman numbers like I, II, III, IV... or looo? Lot of old dactilographers instead of using the digit 1 use lower letter 'L'. Not to mention crazy scientific notations, or numbers with some exotic base other than 2, 8, 10 or 16...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what I've been looking for:

http://site.icu-project.org/

Very powerful library, although at the moment it's not clear whether it can only format or all the formatted stuff can be parsed back as well.